# C, String, File

Tags: c, string, file

A file, named “grades.txt”, contains student grades for a course in the followingformat separated by spaces: (an example file follows)

```
First name Last name Midterm Final
Ali Caliskan 60 40
Veli Dalgaci 80 10
Turkan Sevimli 90 50
Ali Yilmaz 30 70
Ahmet Koc 50 50
```

Write a program which calculates the overall grades of the students and writes them to two separate files: “passed.txt” and “failed.txt”. The midterm is 40 percent of the grade, and the final is 60%. The passing grade is 50. Example output files follow:

```
First name Last name Midterm Final Overall
passed.txt:
Turkan Sevimli 90 50 66
Ali Yilmaz 30 70 54
Ahmet Koc 50 50 50
failed.txt: 
Ali Caliskan 60 40 48
Veli Dalgaci 80 10 38
```

I can read "grades.txt", but i can not store them. This is my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
char* string[100];
char line[100];
char junk[100];

FILE *file = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
if(!file) {
    printf("Could not open file. Exiting application. Bye");
    return 1;
}
while(!feof(file)) {
    fscanf(file,"%[^ \n\t\r]s",line); //Get text
    printf("%s\n", line);
    fscanf(file,"%[ \n\t\r]s",junk); //Remove any 'white space' characters
    }
fclose(file);
}
```

---

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE *pToFile = fopen("grades.txt","r");

    int line = 0;
    char * pch;
    char input[512];

    while( fgets( input, 512, pToFile ))
        {
        line++;
        printf("%s",input);
        }

    printf("\n\nEnd Of Program\n");

    fclose(pToFile);

    return 0;

}
```

I wrote it too, but this one do not separate txt lines and i thought it will be harder to continue with this code.

Comment: Don't control a file-read loop with `feof()`.

Comment: "program gives error". What error? Please be specific.

Comment: Where are you even attempting to write to a file, that you would get an error?  What error are you getting?

Comment: i successfully compile it, when i run it it's stop working

Comment: `strcat(line,str1[100][i]);` What is that meant to do? It is wrong for multiple reasons. 1. `str1` has never been initialised. 2. `str1[100]` is a buffer overflow as `100` is not a valid index for that array. 3. `str1[100][i]` is a `char` not a `char *` as required by `strcat`.

Comment: I tried to store outputs to use later, but yes it was foolish but i tried :D

Comment: Well, that is obviously a problem so try and fix it.

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort, or does your program just stop?

Comment: I fix the error, but i can not find the way to store them. The program's output like that;
Ali-Caliskan-60-40

Comment: "This is my code" should say: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/194292-read-string-from-text-file-and-storing-to-array/page__p__1137063&#entry1137063

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a `struct` for a `Student`.

```
typedef struct {
    char first[25], last[25];
    int midterm, final;
} Student;
```

Then you read from the file and populate your `structs`. You can build up your `struct` from a line with a function like this.

```
  int scan_student(Student *e, const char *line);
```

and use a functions for writing to files.

```
void write_student(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Student *e, double score);
```

Full program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char first[25], last[25];
    int midterm, final;
} Student;

void write_student(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Student *e, double score);

int scan_student(Student *e, const char *line);

enum {
    MAXSTUD = 10
};

int main(void) {
    char line[4096];
    Student stu[MAXSTUD];
    FILE *f = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    FILE *pa = fopen("passed.txt", "w");
    FILE *fa = fopen("failed.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL || pa == NULL || fa == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fa, "First name Last name Midterm Final Overall\n");
    fprintf(pa, "First name Last name Midterm Final Overall\n");
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) == 0)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSTUD && fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != 0; i++) {
        if (scan_student(&stu[i], line) == 0) {
            if (stu[i].midterm * 0.4 + stu[i].final * 0.6 >= 50) {
                write_student(pa, "Student", &stu[i], stu[i].midterm * 0.4 + stu[i].final * 0.6);
            } else {
                write_student(fa, "Student", &stu[i], stu[i].midterm * 0.4 + stu[i].final * 0.6);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(pa);
    fclose(fa);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int scan_student(Student *e, const char *line) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%24s %24s %d %d",
               e->first, e->last, &e->midterm, &e->final) != 4)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

void write_student(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Student *e, double score) {
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %2d %2d %2d\n",
            e->first, e->last, e->midterm, e->final, (int) score);
}
```

Test

```
   $ cat grades.txt 
    First name Last name Midterm Final
    Ali Caliskan 60 40
    Veli Dalgaci 80 10
    Turkan Sevimli 90 50
    Ali Yilmaz 30 70
    Ahmet Koc 50 50⏎                                                                
    $./a.out
    $ cat passed.txt ;cat failed.txt 
    First name Last name Midterm Final Overall
    Turkan Sevimli 90 50 66
    Ali Yilmaz 30 70 54
    Ahmet Koc 50 50 50
    First name Last name Midterm Final Overall
    Ali Caliskan 60 40 48
    Veli Dalgaci 80 10 38
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ^^, but i can not get "Veli Dalgaci 80 10 38" with this code. Why? :S

Answer (score -1):

```html
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char first[25], last[25];
  int midterm;
  int finall;
} Student;

void write_student(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Student *e, double score);

int scan_student(Student *e, const char *line);

int main(void) {
  char line[4096];
  FILE *f = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
  FILE *pa = fopen("passed.txt", "w");
  FILE *fa = fopen("failed.txt", "w");
  fprintf(fa, "First name Last name Midterm Final Overall\n");
  fprintf(pa, "First name Last name Midterm Final Overall\n");
  
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != 0) {
    Student stu;
    if (scan_student(&stu, line) != 0) continue;
    
    if (stu.midterm * 0.4 + stu.finall * 0.6 >= 50) {
      write_student(pa, "Student", &stu, stu.midterm * 0.4 + stu.finall * 0.6);
    } else {
      write_student(fa, "Student", &stu, stu.midterm * 0.4 + stu.finall * 0.6);
    }
  }
  
  fclose(pa);
  fclose(fa);
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}

int scan_student(Student *e, const char *line) {
  if (sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %d",
             e->first, e->last, &e->midterm, &e->finall) != 4)
    return -1;

  return 0;
}

void write_student(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const Student *e, double score) {
  fprintf(fp, "%s %s %d %d %d\n",
          e->first, e->last, e->midterm, e->finall, (int) score);
}
```

SOLVED.

Comment: Wrong format, and an answer with UB, it's not a good answer. Specially when there are only code. You don't verify the return of `fopen()` for example.